# How do I print out this stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
library.stream()
             .map(book -> book.getAuthor())
             .filter(author -> author.getAge() >= 50)
             .map(Author::getLastName)
             .limit(10)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How Do I print out the list? I've tried

```
System.out.println(Collectors.toList());
```

but it gives me

```
 java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl@4ec6a292
```

Comment: Are you assigning the result of that stream to a list? (You should be.) If so then just do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));` or similar.

Comment: @MichaelBerry why on Earth would you do something like `Arrays.toString(list.toArray())` when `list.toString()` produces exactly the same string, i.e. `System.out.println(list);` would be enough?

Comment: @Holger Dah. Because I'm half asleep when I write some comments, I guess.

Comment: @MichaelBerry that’s a fair reason

Answer (score 3):

You need to either get this expression assigned to some list like this,

```
List<String> lastNameList = library.stream()
             .map(book -> book.getAuthor())
             .filter(author -> author.getAge() >= 50)
             .map(Author::getLastName)
             .limit(10)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then print it using,

```
System.out.println(lastNameList);
```

OR you can directly print it like this,

```
System.out.println(library.stream()
             .map(book -> book.getAuthor())
             .filter(author -> author.getAge() >= 50)
             .map(Author::getLastName)
             .limit(10)
             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

You're actually doing this,

```
System.out.println(Collectors.toList());
```

Which has nothing to print except an empty object of type Collectors, which is why you are seeing this,

```
java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl@4ec6a292
```

Comment: Inferring by the object and attribute names, what you've collected should not be a `List<Book>`, possibly a list of lastNames (`List<String>`). Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53245210/1746118)

Comment: Of course, when all you’re going to do with the list, is to print it, you can replace `Collectors.toList()` with `Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]")`, to collect the string representation in the first place.

Comment: @nullpointer: You're right. As that return type was not really important, in hurry I wrote that just like that. I've updated my answer to make it correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use `foreach()` method in `List`

```
library.stream()
    .map(book -> book.getAuthor())
    .filter(author -> author.getAge() >= 50)
    .map(Author::getLastName)
    .limit(10)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want to print collected list here is an example

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(10);
l.add(20);
l.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: .forEach() can be used directly on the list without .stream()

Comment: Thanks for that @Estorskiy

Comment: why doing the `collect`? there is no need for it

Comment: that is OP code, he is trying to collect elements to list @AKSW

Comment: ehm, but your code does a `forEach` at the end, thus, the intermediate list isn't stored in any variable, thus, the `collect` is useless here.

Comment: Agreed, the collect is useless here, one can either store the names using collect or simply iterate over the items to print them using forEach. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53245210/1746118).

Answer (score 1):

This example will give you an idea,

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Stream<String> s = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
        List<String> names = s.collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(names);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Arrays.toString(SomeArray)` or some other method such as a for loop.

When outputting something that does not implement `toString()`, java will just output it in the unreadable format of `Class$Subclass@LocationInMemory`, which doesn't exactly help much.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**Stream.peek**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)) to print the list of `lastName`s of the `author`s above *50* yrs of `age` as following :

```
List<Book> library = List.of(new Book(new Author("overflow", 100)), 
                             new Book(new Author("stack", 80)), 
                             new Book(new Author("nullpointer", 49)));

// you were ignoring the result of collect
List<String> lastNames = library.stream()
            .map(Book::getAuthor)
            .filter(author -> author.getAge() >= 50)
            .map(Author::getLastName)
            .limit(10)
            .peek(System.out::println) // this would print "overflow" and "stack"
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, note if your prime intention is just to print the names and not store them, you can simply use `forEach` instead of `collect`, both of them are terminal operations just that collect has a return type based on the type of Stream while forEach is ***void*** :-

```
library.stream()
       .map(Book::getAuthor)
       .filter(author -> author.getAge() >= 50)
       .map(Author::getLastName)
       .limit(10)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

All of the above, considering the objects in use to being *similar* to the following

```
class Book {
    Author author;

    Book(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    // ... getters
}

class Author {
    String lastName;
    int age;

    Author(String lastName, int age) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // ... getters
}
```